# MarkLogic Custom Facets

Tags: marklogic

I have a facets requirement where I need to group the facets by country  (the country should be generated dynamically as I won't know what values I have within the database)

The top level facet will be retrieve from `<country>` and the rest will be from `<topic order="1">`.

Is there a way to do it?

Sample documents:

```
<doc id="1">
<country>Country 1</country>
<topics>
    <topic order="1">banana</topic>
    <topic order="2">durian</topic>
</topics>
</doc>
```

```
<doc id="2">
<country>Country 2</country>
<topics>
    <topic order="1">banana</topic>
    <topic order="2">apple</topic>
</topics>
</doc>
```

```
<doc id="3">
<country>Country 2</country>
<topics>
    <topic order="1">kit kat</topic>
    <topic order="2">cadbury dairy milk</topic>
</topics>
</doc>
```

```
<doc id="4">
<country>Country 1</country>
<topics>
    <topic order="1">banana</topic>
    <topic order="2">strawberry</topic>
</topics>
</doc>
```

Expected output:

```
Filter by Fruits
================
Country 1   
    banana [2]
    

Country 2
    banana [1]
    kit kat [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had an [element range index](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/admin-guide/en/range-indexes-and-lexicons/defining-element-range-indexes.html) on `country` and a [path-range-index](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/admin-guide/en/range-indexes-and-lexicons/defining-path-range-indexes.html) on `topics/topic[order=1]`, then you could use [`cts:value-co-occurrences()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-co-occurrences) and [`cts:frequency()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:frequency) to produce the desired output:

```
let $countryFacet := map:new()
let $_ :=
  for $entry in 
    cts:value-co-occurrences(
      cts:element-reference(xs:QName("country")), 
      cts:path-reference("topics/topic[@order=1]"), 
      (), 
      cts:true-query())
  let $key := $entry/cts:value[1]
  let $value := $entry/cts:value[2]/text()||" ["||cts:frequency($entry)||"]"
  return map:put($countryFacet, $key, (map:get($countryFacet, $key), $value))   
return
  for $key in map:keys($countryFacet)
  return (
    $key,
    for $value in map:get($countryFacet, $key)
    return "    "||$value
  )
```